# Bottom border is not displaying in the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There are few bottom border issue in the user profile page.

In the [Profile tab](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) - **Top Posts** section, the bottom border is not displaying.

[image: Profile page]

In the [Activity tab](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) - **Questions, Answers, Badges** and **Active bounties** sections, the bottom border is not displaying for the currently selected tab.

[image: Activity page]

When an inspect the element for the issue items the CSS class `youarehere` contains the style `border-color: #FFF;`, this is literally White color. That caused the display issue.

[image: Inspect an element]

**Fix for the bug:**

If apply the `border-color: #265186;` instead of `border-color: #FFF;` in the `youarehere` class, the display issue will solve.

---

**Configurations:**

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Mozilla Firefox: 54.0 (32-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Zoom: 100%

Comment: @pnuts Configurations updated in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good call.

We (well, [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2640230/hynes) mostly) recently did a lot of work to consolidate the bajillion LESS files used for all the Stack Exchange sites. Before that, this bottom border didn't exist on webapps.se, so it was configured to be `white`, i.e. invisible. This actually looks wrong in some places as you found, but even where it doesn't, the current "you are here" highlight was too subtle. So using the `#265186` as you suggested is indeed better.

This will be in the next build. Thanks!